# Spring Boot - JQuery AJAX not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring

Hello I am facing problems with doing my first webclient working with jquery AJAX JSON

Actually if I am pressing submit at my webclient to add a contact to a contact List it is not doing anything for me someone can help me here?
If am using postman to send a request it is working but the informations doesnt display in the index (videolist [html]) it is just showing as usual text in
/url/{id}

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Archiv HTML</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxfunctions.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="centerdiv">
<header><h1>Video Archiv</h1></header>
<section class="left">
<h1>Neues Video anlegen</h1>
<p>
<form id="newVideo">
<label>id:</label>
<input type="text" name="id" required="required" >
<label>vorname:</label>
<input type="text" name="vorname" required="required" >
<label>nachname:</label>
<input type="text" name="nachname" required="required" >
<label>anrede:</label>
<input type="text" name="anrede" required="required" >
<label>adresse:</label>
<textarea name="adresse" required="required" rows="10"></textarea>
<label>telefon:</label>
<input type="text" name="telefon" required="required">
<label>email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" required="required">
<label>handy:</label>
<input type="text" name="handy" required="required" >
<br>
<input type="submit" id="newVideoButton">
</form>
</p>
</section>

<section class="right">
<h1>Meine Videos</h1>
<p>
<button id="loadtable">Laden</button>
<table id="videotable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>vorname</th>
<th>nachname</th>
<th>anrede</th>
<th>adresse</th>
<th>telefon</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>handy</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</p>
</section>

<footer>Tested</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my ajaxfunction:

```
    //On Page load - register listeners and load existing videos in datatable
    $(document).ready(function() {
    loadDataTable();
    //process the form newVideo
    $("#newVideo").submit(function(event) {
        postVideo(event);
    });
    //Load Datatable
    $('#loadtable').click(function() {
        loadDataTable();
    });
});

function postVideo(event) {
    // get the form data
    var formData = {
            'id' : $('input[name=id]').val(),
            'vorname' : $('textarea[name=vorname]').val(),
            'nachname' : $('input[name=nachname]').val(),
            'anrede' : $('input[name=anrede]').val()
            'adresse' : $('input[name=adresse]').val(),
            'telefon' : $('textarea[name=telefon]').val(),
            'email' : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'handy' : $('input[name=handy]').val()
    };
    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to
        use (POST for our form)
    contentType : 'application/json',
    url : '/kontakte', // url where we want to POST
    data : JSON.stringify(formData), // data we want to POST
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
        loadDataTable();
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
    });
    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the
    page
    event.preventDefault();
    }

function loadDataTable() {
    var table = $('#videotable').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/kontakte", //URL
            "dataSrc": "" // Cause of flat JsonObjects
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "vorname" },
            { "data": "nachname" },
            { "data": "anrede" },
            { "data": "adresse" },
            { "data": "telefon" },
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "handy"}
            ]
        });
    }
```

Class Contact:

```
package RestPackage;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class Kontakte {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String vorname;
private String nachname;
private String anrede;
private String adresse;
private String telefon;
private String email;
  private String handy;

  public Kontakte() {}

  public Kontakte(int id, String vorname, String nachname, String anrede, 
  String adresse, String telefon, String email, String handy) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.vorname = vorname;
    this.nachname = nachname;
    this.anrede = anrede;
    this.adresse = adresse;
    this.telefon = telefon;
    this.email = email;
    this.handy = handy;
}

public long getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setID(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getVorname() {
    return vorname;
}

public void setVorname(String vorname) {
    this.vorname = vorname;
}

public String getNachname() {
    return nachname;
}

public void setNachname(String nachname) {
    this.nachname = nachname;
}
public String getAnrede() {
    return anrede;
}

public void setAnrede(String anrede) {
    this.anrede = anrede;
}
public String getAdresse() {
    return adresse;
}

public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
    this.adresse = adresse;
}

public String getTelefon() {
    return telefon;
}

public void setTelefon(String telefon) {
    this.telefon = telefon;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getHandy() {
    return handy;
}

public void setHandy(String handy) {
    this.handy = handy;
}   
}
```

My Controller:

```
package RestPackage;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import RestPackage.Kontakte;


@RestController
public class VerwaltungsController {

@Autowired
VerwaltungsService verwaltungsService;

@RequestMapping ("/kontakte")
public List<Kontakte> getKontakteList(){
    return verwaltungsService.getKontakteList();
}

@RequestMapping("/kontakte/{id}")
public Kontakte getKontakt(@PathVariable Integer id) {
return verwaltungsService.getKontakt(id);
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/kontakte")
public void addKontakt(@RequestBody Kontakte k) {
    verwaltungsService.addKontakt(k);;
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/kontakte/{id}")
public void updateKontakt(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Kontakte 
kontakt) {
    verwaltungsService.updateKontakt(id, kontakt);
}
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/kontakte/{id}")
public void deleteKontakt(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    verwaltungsService.deleteKontakt(id);
}
}
```

Service Class:

```
package RestPackage;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import RestPackage.Kontakte;

@Service
public class VerwaltungsService {

@Autowired
private KontakteRepository kontakteRepository;

public List<Kontakte> getKontakteList() {
    ArrayList<Kontakte> mylist= new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Kontakte> it = kontakteRepository.findAll().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
        mylist.add(it.next());
    return mylist;
}

public Kontakte getKontakt(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return kontakteRepository.findOne(id);
}

public void addKontakt(@RequestBody Kontakte kontakt) {
    kontakteRepository.save(kontakt);

}

public void updateKontakt(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Kontakte 
kontakt) {

    Kontakte k = kontakteRepository.findOne(id);
    k.setVorname(kontakt.getVorname());
    k.setNachname(kontakt.getNachname());
    k.setAdresse(kontakt.getAdresse());
    k.setAnrede(kontakt.getAnrede());
    k.setEmail(kontakt.getEmail());
    k.setHandy(kontakt.getHandy());
    k.setTelefon(kontakt.getTelefon());

    kontakteRepository.save(k);
}

public void deleteKontakt(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    kontakteRepository.delete(id);
}

}
```

CrudRep. Interface:

```
  package RestPackage;


  import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

  import RestPackage.Kontakte;


  public interface KontakteRepository extends CrudRepository<Kontakte, 
  Integer> {


 }
```

Comment: Can you provide the java code?

Comment: sure give me a second

Comment: Where is the spring boot app deployed? Stand-alone or embedded tomcat? I don't see the address specified in the url.

Comment: stand-alone no tomcat

Comment: Where is the complete path to the tomcat?

Comment: Actually I am a bit confused. I did not worked with tomcat. Its just a simple webclient with a mysql db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163357/discussion-between-niver-and-exiizz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `,` missing in the mapping of the input properties. I also advice you to start using the console (key F12) to debug the code and discover problems easly.